# date filter showing function name must be string error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, php-7.1

i'm trying to add date search filter in my controller but always showing error **"Function name must be a string"** attached image below.

Note: my controller already have 2 working search filter one is **Search box** second is **Drop-down**

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPoK6.jpg)

**Controller:**

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{
   //this for search box
    $search=$request->input('search'); 

  // this for drop down list
    if(request()->has('lead_status')){

        $leads=Lead::where('lead_status', request('lead_status'))
        ->paginate(5)
        ->appends('lead_status',request('lead_status'));
    }
    // this for date search from and to
    if($search()->has('from') && $search()->has('to'))
        {
            $from_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($search()->has('from')));
            $to_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($search()->has('to')));
            $leads = Lead::whereBetween('created_at', [$from_date, $to_date]);
        }

    else{

        $leads=Lead::orderBy('created_at','desc')->search($search)->paginate(5);

    }

    return  view ('leads.index')->with('leads',$leads);

}
```

Comment: What is `$search()`? Isn't is just `$search`? `var_dump($search)`, I suppose it's a simple array.

Comment: `$search` is instantiated as an array, and then you're trying to evaluate it with `search()`? This is probably a typo.

Comment: what should i do to fix it? what should i replace on the $search()? how to make date filter?